# V8 (or other JS engine) BigInt Implementation - Displaying as Decimal

Tags: javascript, v8, bigint, spidermonkey

I'm wondering if someone might be able to explain a specific aspect of the JavaScript BigInt implementation to me.

The overview implementation I understand - rather than operating in base 10, build an array representing digits effectively operating in base 2^32/2^64 depending on build architecture.

What I'm curious about is the display/`console.log` implementation for this type - it's incredibly fast for most common cases, to the point where if you didn't know anything about the implementation you'd probably assume it was native. But, knowing what I do about the implementation, it's incredible to me that it's able to do the decimal cast/string concatenation math as quickly as it can, and I'm deeply curious how it works.

A moderate look into [bigint.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/objects/bigint.cc) and [bigint.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/bigint/bigint.h) in the Chromium source has only confused me further, as there are a number of methods whose signatures are defined, but whose implementations I can't seem to find.

I'd appreciate even being pointed to another spot in the Chromium source which contains the decimal cast implementation.

Comment: Think of an extremely large bigint value, and think of how many 64-bit integers that would involve, and then think of how long it takes for a modern CPU to do a few modulus and shift operations on those values. If you're not testing numbers with a hundred thousand or more digits, that decimal formatting is not going to take a significant amount of time.

Comment: "*it's incredibly fast*" - [is it really](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/166)? What numbers did you test with? At least that was not always the case, and [apparently there's still potential for improvements](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=11515).

Comment: "*A moderate look into the source has only confused me further*" - I dunno, isn't the `toString` implementation [right there](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/b4ae834223590d0d6d62588d305dee1629cc2590/src/objects/bigint.cc#945)?

Comment: …and the rest can be found in [*/src/bigint/…*](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/b4ae834223590d0d6d62588d305dee1629cc2590/src/bigint/).

Comment: @Bergi you're right - I should have said, "I'm generally impressed by the speed, as in the admittedly relatively small applications I've tried, out to a few hundred digits, I've not noticed a significant performance degradation when regularly logging them"

Comment: @Bergi also, the `toString` implementation only contains an actual implementation for the case that makes logical sense to me: a BigInt with a single digit; the "generic case" seems to be implemented elsewhere (`isolate->bigint_processor()->ToString(...)`?) and that's what I'm having trouble finding

Comment: `isolate->bigint_processor()->ToString(…)` is calling [`Processor::ToString`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/b4ae834223590d0d6d62588d305dee1629cc2590/src/bigint/tostring.cc#581) which in turn calls [`ProcessorImpl::ToString`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/b4ae834223590d0d6d62588d305dee1629cc2590/src/bigint/tostring.cc#549) which in turn calls [`ProcessorImpl::ToStringImpl`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/b4ae834223590d0d6d62588d305dee1629cc2590/src/bigint/tostring.cc#555) which uses the `ToStringFormatter` defined in that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

@Bergi basically provided the relevant links already, so just to sum it up:

Formatting a binary number as a decimal string is a "base conversion", and its basic building block is:

```
while (number > 0) {
  next_char = "0123456789"[number % 10];
  number = number / 10;  // Truncating integer division.
}
```

(Assuming that `next_char` is also written into some string backing store; this string is being built up from the right.)

Special-cased for the common situation that the BigInt only had one 64-bit "digit" to begin with, you can find this algorithm in code [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/objects/bigint.cc;l=945?q=BigInt::ToString&sq=).

The generalization for more digits and non-decimal radixes is [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/bigint/tostring.cc;l=137?q=ToStringFormatter::Classic); it's the same algorithm.

This algorithm runs sufficiently fast for sufficiently small BigInts; its problem is that it scales quadratically with the length of the BigInt. So for large BigInts (where some initial overhead easily pays for itself due to enabling better scaling), we have a [divide-and-conquer implementation](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/bigint/tostring.cc;l=275?q=ToStringFormatter::Fast) that's built on better-scaling [division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_reduction) and [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) algorithms.

When the requested radix is a power of two, then no such heavy machinery is necessary, because a linear-time implementation is [easy](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/bigint/tostring.cc;l=242?q=ToStringFormatter::BasePowerOfTwo). That's why `some_bigint.toString(16)` is and always will be much faster than `some_bigint.toString()` (at least for large BigInts), so when you need de/serialization rather than human readability, hex strings are preferable for performance.

> if you didn't know anything about the implementation you'd probably assume it was native

What does that even mean?